# Notice: Undefined index: field_brand_image in include() in views field template

Tags: theming

I've got another question about undefined index that I can use help with.

The error message I get is: Notice: Undefined index: field_brand_image in include() on line 15

I'm pretty sure that this is the same lnaguage and "und" portion of the field array issue I had in my other question here: [Notice: Undefined index: und in include()](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/89665/notice-undefined-index-und-in-include)

And only displays when the field is empty

Except this time the error is coming from a views template, the line throwing the error looks like:

```
php print $fields['field_brand_image']->content;
```

I "think" the answer involves an isset conditional, but I don't know what the syntax should be.
I'm using D7.23 and views 7.x-2.3

I'd appreciate some help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing that is using a [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) to check the field as following:

```
<?php print (!empty($fields['field_brand_image'])) ? 
  $fields['field_brand_image']->content : ''; ?>
```

Comment: Just empty on its own is enough. It doesn't give an error when the expression does not exist.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong Yeah right, Thanks for correcting me

Comment: Thank you both again for the help, I really do appreciate it.